# Will Project Avogadro introduce a new constant?

Tags: mass, si-units, metrology

Will the Avogadro Project introduce a new constant?

It seems to me that the aim of the project is to define the kilogramme as some constant number of silicon atoms.

What would this constant be called?

If no name has been suggested, I hereby suggest Pamela's Constant.

Comment: 1) It would most likely be called a standard kilogramme. 2) The chances of any suggestions made by anyone on this site actually influencing science to the level of the name of constant is extremely small; we have no clout. And 3) I'm not sure who this Pamela person is that you refer to, but she would have to be an important scientist and you would need a very good reason for the people, who's job it would be to decide on a name, to even consider taking suggestions from you (or any of us)

Comment: @Jim The suggest is in jest regarding the usage of Silicon.

Comment: I think it can simply be $\frac{1}{28}N_A$, and they would tune the Avogadro's constant to be an exact integer. The current definition is like $\frac{1}{12}N_A$ carbon atoms, so the definitions should be pretty similar and since there isn't a constant for the current definition, no need for a new one too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly subjective question. I do not think there is a need for such a constant. Why? First, lets look at...

#### The definition of the mole

Taken from Wikipedia:

> ... is defined as the amount of a chemical substance that contains as many elementary entities, e.g., atoms, molecules, ions, electrons, or photons, as there are atoms in 12 grams of carbon-12 (<sup>12</sup>C), the isotope of carbon with relative atomic mass 12 by definition.

This definition depends on the definition of the kilogram itself (through gram, a thousandth of a kilogram) to fix a constant, the Avogradro constant $N_A$. In the constant's unitless form, it is the number of atoms in 12g of <sup>12</sup>C, and when given its unit (mol<sup>-1</sup>), it is that same number of atoms **per mole of** <sup>12</sup>C.

#### The project's intended definition

The project aims to reverse the dependence, defining the mole in the first place, and then make the kilogram depend on the mole. How they approach it:

1. Get a piece of silicon, as pure and perfectly crystalline as possible, and make it as close to 1kg as possible
   Fixing its mass near 1kg is so that the new definition of the kilogram produced by this project doesn't make a big impact on how we currently measure things
2. Find the number of atoms in the sample of silicon
   In this step they might settle with a "best approximation" rather than the actual count
3. The best approximation is now the new Avogadro's constant, which *I think* should be an integer
4. Define the molar mass of the silicon atom, which like the mass of the piece of silicon, should also be as close to the current measure as possible.
5. By defining the mole and the molar mass of silicon, one consequently also defines the kilogram, because any fixed number of atoms of fixed mass gives a fixed total mass

#### Conclusion

Because the project would likely yield a definition like:
$$1 kg \equiv \frac{10^3}{M_r} N_AM \times 1mol$$
there doesn't seem to a be need for a new constant, but the Avogadro's constant will almost certainly be tweaked.